# How PAGE table size is calculated here

Tags: operating-system, arm, paging

I am having hard time calculating the page size as from below link:

http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2011/mmucode/

As we know page table entries in this table are 4 bytes long and that there is a maximum of 4096 entries (one for each 1MB of the address space) we can calculate the size of the table as 16KB

Now total size of page table is 4096 entries * 4 bytes wide entry = 16384 bytes = 16kb

But as from above statement each of the 4096 entry corresponds to 1 Mb of address space, that means 1 entry = 1MB .

Since there are 4096 entries, space required to store it is 4096MB but we have page table size of 16kb only.

Also, how many virtual address this 1mb of section has, 250000?

## EDIT:

Sorry, if its going to be more stupid from my end. I tried to understand it again. This 1 Mb of section is part of Physical memory not the virtual memory/page table(which I understood earlier).

Now each entry is 4 Bytes longs, does it means 4 virtual addresses are going to cover 1 Mb of Physical Memory section ?

Comment: 1MB of virtual address space contains 1048576 virtual addresses _by definition_... I can't really understand what the rest of the question is, because the "we know a page table entry takes up 4 bytes, and describes how a 1MB region is mapped, therefore 4 == 1048576 and I have no memory left" reasoning is clearly nonsensical.

Comment: Could you please tell me , how did you calculate it. 1MB = 1024KB and 1024KB = 1024 * 1024 Bytes = 1048576 and each address takes 4byets ,so virtual addresses = 1048574 % 4 = 262144 ?

Comment: What? No. There are 4096 virtual 1MB regions, which can each map to one of 4096 physical 1MB regions (or nothing, or a finer-grained layout described by a level 2 table, but let's ignore that). That's what the 12 bits of address in the PTE represent. The lower bits of the VA form an offset into that virtual region, and the same offset into the physical region makes the resulting PA. See e.g. [these illustrations](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch12s03.html) (public AArch64 version for illustration, but register an account and grab the ARMv7-A guide for specifics).

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point that lower 12 bits of address used as an page offset or index into a page.Also, I got that there 1048576 VA in 1 MB(Memory is byte addressable). But as you said there 4096 virtual 1MB regions, would it mean page table size = 4096* 1MB?

Comment: The page table is 16k in size.  The space it can map (meaning virtual to physical) is 4G (4096*1MB), which is 32bits of address space.  So the L1 table is only as big as it needs to be; it must also be aligned to 16k!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the question is asking but in a typical AArch32 MMU (barring the newer extensions), you would have first and second level translation tables in a typical configuration.

The first level translation table splits the entire address space into 1MB sections and typically contain pointers to level 2 tables which split those 1MB sections into granular pages (traditionally 4KB on most machines). 2nd level translation tables store physical addresses that correspond to those virtual addresses (each entry stores a physical address along with some flags). The virtual address is determined by its position within the L1 and L2 tables. To further clarify, all addresses stored in page tables (including addresses to L2 tables in the L1 table) are **physical**.

The first level translation table has a fixed size but depending on which architecture you're running you can change its size (this is used by a lot of ARM kernels to provide a user/kernel address space split). Each gigabyte of virtual memory space requires 4096 bytes in the L1 table at 4096 byte page size.

To even further clarify as far as I remember you can use L1 entries to map 1MB chunks directly without using L2 tables, the type of L1 entry is denoted by lower bits of it.

*(Sorry if I got the unit suffixes wrong)*